# Android Instrumentation testing

Tags: android, mocking, instrumentation

I am writing a test case for my android activity. The activity has two textboxes and a button. When the button is pressed i make a call to a web service and the application responds accordingly. Now for my test i want to only test how my GUI is acting for a positive response. I am not concerned about the network architecture as that will be tested separately. Is it possible for me to change the behavior of my application, like i change the class of my asynctask to a mock class so it always returns true. Is this possible. If not how can i do what i want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

pass a debug boolean param or such into the async task and if true then give dummy data if false then goto the server for data.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Boolean... debug) {

        if(debug[0]){
            //do your dummy here
            return "blah blah blah";
        } 

        return GetWebData();

  }      

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
  }

}
```